# Count nested divs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hey I need to count the nested divs with a given class name. For example:

```
<div id = "divA">
    <div class = "anotherName"></div>
    <div class = "toBeCounted"></div>
    <div class = "someName"></div>
    <div class = "toBeCounted"></div>
    <div class = "toBeCounted"></div>
    <div class = ""></div>
</div>
<div id = "divB">
    <div class = ""></div>
    <div class = "toBeCounted"></div>
    <div class = ""></div>
    <div class = "toBeCounted"></div>
</div>
```

So if I want to count "toBeCounted" I would get 3 for divA and 2 for divB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `.querySelectorAll()` and check the length of the result:

```
var divAcount = document.querySelectorAll("#divA > .toBeCounted").length;
```

The `>` relation insists that the `.toBeCounted` elements are immediate children of `divA`. If that's not what you want, and *any* `toBeCounted` div within `divA` should count, you'd just leave out the `>`.

Comment: This assumes that the OP isn't targeting IE browsers < 8 (and hopefully they aren't)

Comment: @ElGuapo yes that's true - it's all part of my project to make IE8 go away by convincing the world that it can't possibly be real

Comment: HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA

Answer (score 2):

try this pure javascript code

```
var countinDivA = document.getElementById("divA").getElementsByClassName("toBeCounted").length;
var countinDivB = document.getElementById("divB").getElementsByClassName("toBeCounted").length;
```

Answer (score 1):

With Jquery this can be easily achieved by using

```
var countA = $("#divA .toBeCounted").length;
var countB = $("#divB .toBeCounted").length;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the id's of the parents ahead of time, this may prove useful:

```
var parents = [],
    counted = document.getElementsByClassName("toBeCounted");

for (var i=0; i < counted.length; i++ ) { 
    var id = counted[i].parentNode.id;
    if ( !parents[id] ) parents[id] = 1
    else parents[id]++;
}
```

---

```
[ divA: 3, divB: 2 ]
```